# Error when attempting to launch and debug project after moving project to a new folder

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I've moved my project to another folder and now I'm now getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError /Users/user/Documents/project/project.ts:1
import express from "express";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)

No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

Although, I didn't move the project, I cloned a version from the repository into another folder.

The debug view shows the difference:

In original working project:

[image]

In the new non-working project:

[image]

New project jtsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "stripInternal": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

New project package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Clicking on the small debug "button" shows this:

[image]

**Update:**
I closed vscode and restarted. And a few things changed. The debug panel was blank but now it shows this:

[image]

I click on the create a launch.json and it shows this

[image]

I thought I already have a launch json in the vscode folder???

Comment: show the package.json's `type` field and the tsconfig.json

Comment: I don't see a type field in package.json. I've added the tsconfig.json

Comment: Try adding `"type": "module"` to your package.json. [See docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type). Excerpt "_Files ending with .js are loaded as ES modules when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module"_" I see you're using `ts-node`, but try it anyway. I want to see if it will work.

Comment: How is all this new information you've added related to your original error in `project.ts`?

Comment: @user well, now the debug buttons are gone and a new screen is shown. i've added a screen shot. the new information added is because to launch the program i've been pressing the launch and debug button that has now disappeared. although i also tried launching using node myproject.js.in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I got it to work. I had to restart vscode. I had a few error messages about extension and [corrupt installation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported).
[image]
[image]

At some point a small debug button appeared in package.json. It might have appeared before or after restart.

[image]

The debug panel that was blank but now it shows a few new buttons and messages.

Blank:
[image]

Not blank:
[image]

It was blank before (meaning it showed the panels panes but there was no content in them.

I then clicked the, `Create a launch.json` and choose `node.js` as the type of launch.

This created a new launch.json with default values for that launch type:

[image]

I now have a new option in the Run and Debug panel:

[image]

Selecting this option and clicking on the launch button successfully launches the app.

Conclusion,

My guess is that vscode didn't like the existing launch.json config. I would delete the existing launch config and let vscode create it, then add in any new values later. I would also restart after the initial opening of the workspace.